# Replace iPhone Emoji in HTML page

Tags: php, html, iphone, ios, emoji

I am sending a string from iphone app to server.
That string may contain Emoji - I am encoding and sending that.
From server side they are showing it in an html page,How can they convert the string into EMOJI charecters

my string is like this

```
testing \ud83d\ude04 my \ud83d\udc0e Emoji \ud83c\udf85 hureee \u260e hai \ud83d\udeb2
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the JSON encoding of Unicode characters (as a UTF-16 surrogate pair). `json_decode()` should properly decode that:

```
<?php
    $json = '{"key":"testing \ud83d\ude04 my \ud83d\udc0e Emoji \ud83c\udf85 hureee \u260e hai \ud83d\udeb2"}';
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj->{'key'};
?>
```

Output:

```
testing  my  Emoji  hureee ☎ hai
```

Comment: emoji works expected ...does we can sent without key

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with the list of these particular strings along with another array containing their replacements (e.g. images), then use the PHP command **preg_replace** in this way:

```
  <?php

    $originalString = 'testing \ud83d\ude04 my \ud83d\udc0e Emoji \ud83c\udf85 hureee \u260e hai \ud83d\udeb2';
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/\\\\ud83d\\\\ude04/';
    $patterns[1] = '/\\\\ud83d\\\\udc0e/';
    $patterns[2] = '/\\\\ud83c\\\\udf85/';
    $patterns[3] = '/\\\\ud83c\\\\udf85/';
    $patterns[4] = '/\\\\u260e/';
    $patterns[5] = '/\\\\ud83d\\\\udeb2/';
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[5] = '<img src="image6URL" alt="alternative text" />';
    $replacements[4] = '<img src="image5URL" alt="alternative text" />';
    $replacements[3] = '<img src="image4URL" alt="alternative text" />';
    $replacements[2] = '<img src="image3URL" alt="alternative text" />';
    $replacements[1] = '<img src="image2URL" alt="alternative text" />';
    $replacements[0] = '<img src="image1URL" alt="alternative text" />';

    $newString = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $originalString);

echo  $newString;

?>
```

$newString will be the resulting string that you can use as an output in your HTML page.

Notice that the [backward slashes in the emoji must be escaped using 3 additional backward slashes in the regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).